# Java Arrays: Locate the index of the stored value in an array. Is

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a program that lets the user enter 10 numbers stored in an array. I already have the code that will determine the minimum and maximum numbers entered by the user all I'm having problems with is how to display the index where the maximum and minimum value is located.

Here are my codes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numbers[] = new int[10];
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE, largest = numbers[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
//I get the "Can't find symbol error" on this part: index = i;

            index = i;
            System.out.print("Array Number " + i + ": ");
            numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for (int n = 0 ; n < numbers.length; n++) {
            if (numbers[n] < smallest) {
                smallest = numbers[n];
            } 
            if (numbers[n] > largest) {
                largest = numbers[n];
            }      

        }

//And this part, which it the: index

        System.out.println("Maximum number is " + largest + " located in index " + index);
        System.out.println("Minimum number is " + smallest + " located in index " + index);

    }   

}
```

I want to know which part I got it wrong.

Comment: `index` is not defined.

Comment: remove index=i;  note in here `i` is basically used as your `index`

Comment: you are using the same variable index or you are hoping to use it to tell you the index of both highest & the lowest? You need two different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` is not defined, therefore you get an error there.

```
int index = i;
```

For finding the index of the smallest and largest number, you will need two indices which you update whenever you find a smaller or larger value. You don't even need to save `smallest` and `largest`, since they are stored in the array anyways and can be retrieved using the two indices (thanks to Andrew S. for mentioning):

```
int maxIndex = -1, minIndex = -1;

for (int n = 0 ; n < numbers.length; n++) {
    if (numbers[n] < smallest) {
        smallest = numbers[n];
        minIndex = n;
    } 
    if (numbers[n] > largest) {
        largest = numbers[n];
        maxIndex = n;
    }      
}

System.out.println("Maximum number is " + numbers[maxIndex]+ " located in index " + maxIndex);
System.out.println("Minimum number is " + numbers[minIndex] + " located in index " + minIndex);
```

Comment: Note that tracking the indexes as `minIndex` and `maxIndex` is enough to determine the actual value.  The smallest _value_ is `numbers[minIndex]`  and the largest _value_ is  `numbers[maxIndex]`, so `smallest` and `largest` are not needed.